# Kivy Buildozer VM - Can't build apk - Build failed: python-for-android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I try to build apk on Buildozer VM

```
[ERROR]:   Build failed: python-for-android no longer supports running 
under Python 2. Either upgrade to Python 3.4 or higher (recommended), or 
revert to python-for-android 2019.07.08. Note that you *can* still target 
Python 2 on Android by including python2 in your requirements.

Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create -- 
dist_name=MyApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,plyer,python2 --arch 
arm64-v8a --copy-libs --color=always --storage- 
dir="/home/kivy/Projects/MyApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk- 
api=21

**pip freeze:**
...
buildozer==0.39
Cython==0.29.13
python-for-android==2019.7.8


**buildozer.spec:**
...
requirements = kivy,plyer,python2
```

Unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem for several days.
Maybe someone managed to solve

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run buildozer/python-for-android with python2, but you need to use python3 (like it says). Uninstall buildozer, and install it with python3.

Comment: Note that you *can* still target 
Python 2 on Android by including python2 in your requirements.

Comment: That is also true, but not relevant here.